# find the difference between 2 times of type char in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 times `start_time` and `end_time` of type char. How to find the difference between them?

For example my `start_time` is 10:00 AM and `end_time` is 11:15 AM, then time difference should display 1:15

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
declare @starttime varchar(10)='10:00 AM'
declare @endtime varchar(10)='11:15 AM'
select cast((datediff(Mi,convert (time,@starttime),
            convert (time,@endtime))/60) as varchar(5))+':'+
       cast((datediff(Mi,convert (time,@starttime),
              convert (time,@endtime))%60) as varchar(5))
```

### **result**

```
1:15
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the difference in minutes:

```
select DATEDIFF (minute, starttime, endtime)
```

See [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT left(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF
(ms, CAST('10:00 AM' AS DATETIME), CAST('11:15 AM' AS DATETIME)) , 0), 108),5);
```

**Result**

> 01:15

```
SELECT left(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF
(ms, CAST('09:00 AM' AS DATETIME), CAST('11:15 AM' AS DATETIME)) , 0), 108),5);
```

**Result**

> 02:15

[See this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dd39/27)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(convert(varchar,CAST('11:15 AM AS DATETIME)-CAST('10:00 AM' AS DATETIME),108),5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it works fine in MySQL:

```
select TIME_FORMAT((TIME( STR_TO_DATE( '11:15 PM', '%h:%i %p' ) ) - TIME( STR_TO_DATE( '10:00 PM', '%h:%i %p' ))),'%h:%i');
```

Comment: Question's tag says: "sql-server".