# how to add 2 varchar columns in sql

Tags: sql

I have timediff field as `varchar`

I want to find sum of this field but it gives error as

`"Syntax error converting the varchar value '02:00' to a column of data type int."`

My timediff is like

```
02:00
03:00
04:00
```

i want to add and should display `9` in sql

please help me

thanks for helping me

Comment: Will you show us what you have tried??

Comment: 02:00 is not an Int number. You can convert the hour (2) or the minutes (0) to Int, but both together not

Comment: Why not store the timediff in minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `SUM` on a varchar column.  Take a look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx).

You haven't given us much information about what you are storing or how you want it summed, but your best bet might be to parse out the number before your colon, convert it to an int and sum that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **MS SQL**

You could do something like this

first convert your hour representation to minutes by this

```
select (CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING('02:00',1,2))*60) +
         CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING('02:00',4,2))
```

---

Then use that minutes representation to perform addition like this

```
select 
DATEADD(
    minute,
    (select (CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING('02:00',1,2))*60) +
     CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING('02:00',4,2))),
    getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

If your final goal is to get sum of all datadiff records in `hh:mm` then first store datediff in minutes instead of `hh:mm` which you asked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900730/find-the-difference-between-2-times-of-type-char-in-sql)

How to store DateDiff in minutes:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second,CAST(<timepart> AS DATETIME) 
, CAST(<timepart> AS DATETIME))/60.0 AS MIN_DIFF;
```

For example

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second,CAST('10:00 AM' AS DATETIME) 
, CAST('11:15 AM' AS DATETIME))/60.0 AS MIN_DIFF;
```

How to do sum of all minutes in `hh:mm`

```
SELECT CAST((<total minutes> / 60) AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':' 
+ CAST((<total minutes> % 60) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

For example

```
SELECT CAST((390 / 60) AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':' 
+ CAST((390 % 60) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

[See this fiddle for all your answers.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dd39/38)